# Tunnel Socks Proxy through Privoxy

Tags: proxy, tunnel, socks-proxy, socks5, privoxy

I'm using Privoxy to tunnel a specified SOCKS5 Proxy through Privoxy. It works just fine.
Is there any way to tunnel through multiple dynamic proxys just by setting up a single listening endpoint on my local machine? E.g. when I make an HTTP request to "http://www.example.net.127.0.0.1:9050.exit/" Privoxy should resolve the connect to "http://www.example.net/" with proxy "127.0.0.1:9050"

Any suggestions? Can I achieve this with "forward" section or action files?

Comment: You need to use a [proxy server](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_server) that uses Privoxy. See examples in User Manual section [Forwarding](https://www.privoxy.org/user-manual/config.html#FORWARDING). More examples in the Forwarding chapter [here](https://lueersen.homedns.org/privoxy_HTML/user-manual/configuration.html).

Comment: Do I need to reconfigure privoxy every time my client sends a different SOCKS Proxy he wants to connect to? I need some posibility to connect on a per request base. Means my privoxy instance doesn't know about the existing of the SOCKS Proxies at the time of configuration.

Comment: I think I misunderstood your question. Is it that you are looking for a fast method of programming Privoxy to switch the proxy and connect to a website? If yes, then this is partly a job for Privoxy and partly for the browser.

Comment: Yes, you got me right, sorry for my English. But my "browser" is not as powerful to connect with the SOCKS protocol. He just understands HTTP. Privoxy does the job great if you have a single or a bunch of proxies you can set up in your config but if you want to have just one instance of privoxy running connecting to different proxies per clients request I didn't had any luck yet how to achieve this. Maybe with another tool?

Comment: I can code the client in a way that he might sent special headers for the proxy or a specific scheme in the requested URL (like in my question) but I don't want to implement the full SOCKS protocol.